# Yii 1.1: Race Condition when reading $_COOKIE used to identify user

Tags: php, yii, session-cookies, yii1.x

I am experiencing a race condition when 2 users (almost) simultaneously access the same page.  This causes the user to gain access to another users data.

I have been trying to catch this issue for some months and have finally managed to do so.
I am using Yii Framework 1.1 and the user login process is as follows:

- Sessions are stored in the database, I dont actually use $_SESSION to store anything.
- A generated Session ID is stored in a cookie and populates $_COOKIE which is used by PHP to connect the user to their data.
- From the login page, I store the Session ID from the cookie in a field of the form.
- The user logs in, input is validated, Session Data is created and stored with the user record, including the Session id from the form (the real Session ID).  The user is then routed through 2 more controllers (LoginCheck, Dashboard) to land on the Dashboard.
- During a session, the user will frequently return to the dashboard.
- When 2 or more users access the dashboard page (almost) simultaneously (via login or returning from a page within the site), both users will end up with the same cookie id and session data.  I can confirm this by checking the browser based cookie with the cookie value stored in the $_COOKIE variable.  A simple refresh of the dashboard on the page with the incorrect data results in the correct data being loaded.

I have researched race conditions with sessions in PHP and some of these offer the use of $_COOKIE to resolve race conditions with sessions so not really providing me with any solutions to my problem.

As I am able to trap the issue, I can easily resolve it with a refresh, but if there is a more stable solution available I would prefer to go down that route.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It sounds like your session ID generation is timestamp-based. For example, if you're using [`uniqid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) then this would be a very easy cause for your problem. You should look into an alternative method of ID generation using cryptographically secure values, e.g. via [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) or [`random_bytes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php).

Comment: Apart from that possibility, we can't really assist you without seeing any actual code. This problem could be caused by any number of things. We would need to see code in order to narrow it down.

Comment: There is something really wrong with your session management. `session_id()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php is always unique per session. There is no way users from different browsers will get same session id. Until you artificially replace it with your broken implementation. It is unrelated to _race condition_

Comment: the problem with supplying the code is most of it comes from the Yii framework so I have been presuming/trusting that it will work as expected.  Its been difficult to track down how and when this occurs, but I have managed to do that now.

Comment: @GregJ We don't necessarily need your framework boilerplate code, but knowing which class(es) you're using to store the session data and/or generate the session ID and any application-specific session-related code would be good to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fopen with x or x+ flag to a shared file. Only one of the instances can open the file simultaneously.

**However** what you describe is inconsistent and weird: you should not need to deal with race conditions while using sessions as you describe. I guess that the problem is that you regenerate the session id on each page load, so you are probably doing something you shouldn't.

On sessions each user agent must generate a session id only once, but as you describe that id is regenerated on each page change, and as a secondary problem it's generated with low entropy.

If you fix the first problem, then the low entropy problem will be mitigated, but not solved.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion but the session id is not regenerated on each page load.  The SessionID is stored in a cookie when the session is created and that cookie remains until either the session expires or the user logs out.  I am using the core functionality provided by the Yii Framework, how that actually works under the covers isnt something I completely understand as yet.